# PHP in URL to locate specific node in XML db

Tags: php, xml

i'm totally new to XML, but am trying it out on a site of mine to iterate through a very easy db.  what i can't figure out is how to post a link outside of the site to a specific node in the xml database.  the site in question is (http://thenewsomething.com)

please forgive any obvious ignorance as this is my first attempt with xml.  what i'd like to do is post a url elsewhere that will link to thenewsomething.com with one of the specific nodes.  for instance, if i give each node an id, can i do something like

http://thenewsomething.com?id=5

? thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: an xml document is typically not a database. it's usually just a flat file. you will have much more functionality and better performance using a real database like mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. In PHP, you can look at `$_GET['id']` to read out the ID passed to your script by the URL. (Make sure you escape the input by using something like addslashes). If your script is called index.php and someone browses to index.php?id=5, you can do this:

```
<?php
$id = addslashes($_GET['id']);
#use code tailored to your specific database to fetch the node with this ID 
#display it
?>
```

You can look into something like SimpleXML and XPath to search within your XML database. For a quick introduction to XPath, consider:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

If you post details of your XML schema, we may be able to help more.

Comment: thanks so much, i got busy doing some other stuff and totally forgot i even asked this on here but thanks for the answer.